# Best way to examine mortality tables?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, survival

I have a set of tables containing mortality rates (hazard rates) and I want to see how well these values reflect the influence of the covariates (age, sex, issue year, etc.). I also have 
actual mortality experience.

I was thinking of using a Poisson regression with the independent variables being the covariates  plus the *log* of the tabular mortality values, because that has a linear relationship with actual deaths. I plan on doing it this way because if any of the variables representing the covariates turns out to be significant, it would mean that the mortality values have not been properly "priced" for that factor and need to be adjusted.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?